# How to allow guest to access home page without login in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I want that the home page and other pages be accessible for everyone without login in Spring Security. I used this code but it forces me to login. This is the code:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/secure**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/home**").anonymous()
            .and()
            .formLogin().permitAll();

}
```

I enter `localhost:8080/` but it redirects me to `/login`

Answer (score 4):

Add `.antMatchers("/").anonymous()`

`.anyRequest().authenticated()` means that the user must be *logged in*, i.e. *not anonymous*, but with no specific role requirement.

You can combine them, e.g. `.antMatchers("/", "/home**").anonymous()`