# Spring Boot Security - allow without authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web, spring-security

### Spring boot security allow anonymous user

I am trying configure Spring Boot Security to allow anonymous user reach all URLs except one. By default user and generated security password by Spring.
I need just one page for maintanance application
I already tried a lot tips and tutorials.

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24696717/spring-security-permitall-not-allowing-anonymous-access)
[2](https://www.baeldung.com/security-none-filters-none-access-permitAll)
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57275361/how-to-allow-guest-to-access-home-page-without-login-in-spring-security)
[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36809561/spring-security-thymleaf-static-resources-dont-load)

And others.

But Spring still required authetification for all pages.

**My current security config**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConf extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest()
        .anonymous()
        .antMatchers("/secure")
        .authenticated();
    }
}
```

**Web configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAsync
public class WebConf implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        WebMvcConfigurer.super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("/webjars/**");
    }   
    @Bean
    public Executor asyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(5);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Asynchronous Process-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }   
}
```

**And main method**

```
@ComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class MainServiceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I tried

```
.permitAll()
.anonymous()
```

without success.

**Edit 1**

---

Project structure

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipx48.png)

**Edit 2**

---

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NVks.png)

```
@ComponentScan()
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class MainServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

[Login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFE9C.png)

**Solved by move config package. Spring did not scan configuration package.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to change the order. Possible issue is  `antMatchers("/secure").authenticated()` has no effect due to */secure* endpoint will be considerd in the `anyRequest()`. Also make sure `SecurityConf` is in correct package as required for scanning.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConf extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/secure").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().anonymous();
    }
}
```

OR

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConf extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/secure").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

You need to create a *configs* package inside `cz.lh.main_service` and `SecurityConf` and `WebConf` should be part of the `cz.lh.main_service.configs`

OR

You can use `@ComponentScan` and can specify the current package in which you have `SecurityConf` and `WebConf`

```
@ComponentScan(“your-config-package”)
```

Comment: Not working :(  SecurityConf share same package as WebConf. Can be issue in scanning ?

Comment: @LubošHájek, can you edit the question with the project structure?

Comment: Also, make sure you don't have security annotations at the controller level such as `@Secured`, `@PreAuthorized` etc